# iPhone and SQLite: How to handle the database connection with multiple classes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, performance, sqlite

I have some doubts about SQLite...
My app uses only one table (encapsulated in a data logic class) to store small data, the connection is opened in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and finalized in `applicationWillTerminate` (yes, I know that in iOS4 `applicationWillTerminate` is only called by iSO if necessary, but I write on database at every change of data).

Now I have to add a second table (and relative class) that will store different data (no join between the two tables) and of normal size (about 1-2 rows for day).

I thought of applying the singleton pattern to share the connection and the statements, but I read that for performance reason it's recommended to use class-local variables to hold the connection.

So what's the best practice? Singleton or two open connection?
What solution would you reccommend for my situation?

Thanks

Comment: For such a simple database, writing SQLite code by hand is a complete waste of time.  Use CoreData.  Much simpler, very likely much faster, and a heck of a lot easier to maintain & evolve.

Comment: Please add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a simple use, a singleton is probably the right answer for the very reasons that @Eiko mentions.

However, it all begs the question:  Why aren't you using Core Data?

Using SQLite correctly is actually quite hard and I've seen dozens of very talented/experienced engineers get it entirely wrong without realizing it.   Worse, scaling an existing implementation is even harder.  Adding concurrency is really **really** hard with straight SQLite (and the Core Data engineers have expended a huge amount of energy and applied a ton of expertise to support concurrency on top of SQLite correctly).

For such a simple use, Core Data won't be hard to learn and it will leave you with a much more solid and versatile code base.

Answer (score 2):

Singleton for me when stored in the same database.

Small amounts of data shouldn't be a performance bottleneck anytime soon.

Or, of course, go with CoreData. :-)